# Need help learning to write tests for this Android app (Kotlin, MVVM, Room, Dagger2)

Tags: android, database, unit-testing, mvvm, kotlin

https://github.com/Spheniscine/dimsum-leadmanagement

I am currently a beginner to Android development.

This is an Android app I am currently working on, notes on its current working state is in the description. I am currently trying to learn how to write more robust code using MVVM (Model-View-View Model) for a testable architecture, and was supposed to learn TDD (test-driven development) patterns, but I seem to have hit a snag as to writing the actual tests.

There are a number of instrumented tests already here testing the simplest navigation stuff, but I am having trouble figuring out the best way to write tests for things like whether a salesperson shows up on the list or whether adding a salesperson works, without referencing or affecting the actual database on the phone. I'm also struggling to write unit tests for the backend (SalespersonMngViewModel and DimsumRepository)

From what I can glean, I need to use something called Dagger to inject a mock database or repository as needed... as evidenced by the "di" folder, I have managed to use it to make the repository injectable, however I am having trouble figuring out how to actually use it for testing. Additionally, I am having trouble figuring out how to extend that pattern to inject the ViewModel. From the tutorials and info I looked around for, it seems to require something called a ViewModelFactory, which again, I am having trouble understanding how to implement.

The problem is that the tutorials I found either talked about a whole bunch of other dependencies (e.g. Retrofit, RxJava, Glide) that I haven't had time to learn about yet, or were missing key features or use cases that I needed (e.g. there was an MVVM tutorial I followed that didn't have testing, and then there was a testing tutorial that used MVVM, but with neither a Room database nor dependency injection)